# Extract parts of text using sed,awk

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed, awk, grep

I've below text, how can I extract list

[83472, 8327489] and abcd: 32324 ?

```
[83472, 8327489]abcd: 32324Expr bla bla
[243fd]abcd: 4342Expr ieddsk
[2324, 34543, 8937423]abcd: 3232432423423Expr bla bla
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -E 's/(\[[^]]*\]abcd:[[:blank:]]*[[:digit:]]*).*/\1/' file
```

should do it.

**Sample Output**

```
[83472, 8327489]abcd: 32324
[243fd]abcd: 4342
[2324, 34543, 8937423]abcd: 3232432423423
```

Comment: Why not just `sed -E 's/Expr.*//' file` ?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem That would not work in the rare cases like `[Expr. 8327489] abcd: 32324Expr bla bla`

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and pcre

1) to extract upto but not including `Expr` and rest of line

```
$ grep -oP '.*(?=Expr)' file
[83472, 8327489]abcd: 32324
[243fd]abcd: 4342
[2324, 34543, 8937423]abcd: 3232432423423
```

2) to extract `[...]abcd: numbers`

```
$ grep -oP '\[[^]]*\]abcd:\s*\d+' file
[83472, 8327489]abcd: 32324
[243fd]abcd: 4342
[2324, 34543, 8937423]abcd: 3232432423423
```